# Python - print text if action is true

Tags: python, printing, if-statement

I'm trying to get Python to print a sentence if it successfully copies a file. While it copies the file, it ignores the print. why is this? here's a similar example of my code:

```
from shutil import copyfile

if copyfile('/Library/demo.xls','/Jobs/newdemo.xls'):
  print "the file has copied"
```

For reference, I'm using Python v2.7.1

Comment: Because it doesn't know if it succeeded until after the copy finishes?  For example, if the filesystem fills up mid-copy.

Answer (score 9):

`copyfile` does not return anything, but it throws an exception if an error occurs. Use the following idiom instead of the `if` check:

```
import shutil

try:
    shutil.copyfile('/Library/demo.xls','/Jobs/newdemo.xls')
except (Error, IOError):
    # Handle error
    pass
else:
    # Handle success
    print "the file has copied"
```

Link to the [`shutil.copyfile` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html).

Answer (score 4):

That's because `shutil.copyfile` returns `None`. You probably want to wrap it in a `try`/`except` clause instead:

```
try:
    shutil.copyfile(file1, file2)
    print 'success!'
except shutil.Error:
    print 'oh no!'
```

Answer (score 0):

copyfile doesn't return a value (well, returns None).